# Display related products on sidebar

Tags: magento2, layout, product-page, sku

I want to display related products if they exist on the sidebar on product page over featured products.
[image]

Please advise

EDIT
ADDED catalog_product_view.xml code

```
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>

    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="service-sidebar" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">service-sidebar</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">
        <block class="Sm\Autostore\Block\Template" name="view.count" after="-"
               template="Magento_Theme::html/view-count.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="detail-extended" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">detail-extended</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="social.button.detail"
               after="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/social-button.phtml"
               ifconfig="autostore/product_detail/show_social_button"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info"
               after="product.info.price">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="page.bottom">
        <container name="bottom-related-upsell" label="Related Upsell" as="bottom-related-upsell" htmlTag="div"
                   htmlClass="container">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related.theme"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/related-upsell.phtml"
                   ifconfig="autostore/product_detail/show_related">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto"
                       as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell.theme"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/related-upsell.phtml"
                   ifconfig="autostore/product_detail/show_upsell">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto"
                       as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Add your catalog_product_view.xml code in your question.

Comment: added mate. can you please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

If you configured related products in admin then you can move related products where you want in your Product view page.

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="block-name-where-you-want-to-place-it" />
```

block-name-where-you-want-to-place-it -replace your featured product block name here.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it would be better if you add file name/path in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code in your **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<move element="catalog.product.related.theme" destination="sidebar.main" before="-" />
```

But the design will not look like the **Featured Products** Section, You have to add styles fort this, Because if in your theme Related Products Section is in full-width at bottom of the product page.
Check this: http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_autostore/default/acdelco-335-professional.html

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. This indeed displayed related products where i wanted but the result was not good. Can you please advise me how i can add style?